# ASP.NET how to pass value from form to another page

Tags: asp.net, .net

i have page with the url that show my list of items:

https://localhost:123/AllSystems/List?systemTypeID=1

and inside this page i have search (i pass SearchTerm to list.cshtml.cs file ):

```
<form method="get">
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="input-group">
        <input type="search" class="form-control" asp-for="SearchTerm" />
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span> **Search**
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
</form>
```

when i click on Search button (inside the search form) i go to url:
https://localhost:123/AllSystems/List?SearchTerm=nba

that fine but i want to pass the systemTypeID=1 to from last url 
(https://localhost:123/AllSystems/List?systemTypeID=1).
how i do it?

i want the result be something like that: 
https://localhost:123/AllSystems/List?systemTypeID=1&SearchTerm=nba

thank's

Answer (score 0):

you can pass multiple dynamic values to QueryString as below
you can set `Value1` and `Value2` and pass that values to your query string as below

```
string value1="1";
string value2="nba";


Response.Redirect("https://localhost:123/AllSystems/List?systemTypeID"+value1+"&SearchTerm="+value2);
```

in second page you can access the value like

```
string typeid= Request.QueryString["systemTypeID"];
string searchvalue = Request.QueryString["SearchTerm"];
```

Comment: Either you can pass store values in session ans you can access it anywhere in application